# Tool for testing using parameter permutations

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, parameters

I remember there existed a testing program/library that will run your code and/or unit tests, creating all kinds of permutations of the parameters (null values, random integers, strings and so on). I just can't remember what it was called and searching google doesn't seem to come up with anything.

I know it was created for Java code and I think it was quite expensive as well. That's really all I can remember, anyone have a clue what program/library I am thinking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AgitarOne JUnit Generator](http://www.agitar.com/solutions/products/automated_junit_generation.html) comes to mind. I'm not sure it's what you're thinking of, though.

Comment: well, it does what stian described, it's written in Java, and it's very expensive, so probably correct :)

Answer (score 0):

JTest from Parasoft may be what you're thinking of.